# Eclipse Cannot create in-place editor

Tags: java, eclipse, class

I have a troubleshoot problem. My eclipse don't want open class in the package editor.

Error, what i'm having - [image]

However, file opened with Open with->Text Editor. 
That's looks like a charm kinda. help please.

Comment: Hmm the first thing I would try is to reinstall.

Comment: Worst case: use the project explorer.

Comment: Try changing the Workspace`s enconding. Go to Preferences > General > Workspace and change the enconding in the bottom box. I use UTF-8 here

Comment: This happens only with one file in my system.

Comment: can you attach the file it's happening?

Comment: @SergeyFedorov it's happening for every file in system

Comment: What is the type of file you are trying to open? Java sourcecode, or something else? [This blog post](https://maheeka.wordpress.com/2012/07/23/ole-exception-in-eclipse-for-msoffice-files/) seems related, even the same `result` code, whatever that means.

Comment: i working with `*.java` and `*.js`

Comment: `This happens only with one file in my system.` ... `it's happening for every file in system` ... I'm a little confused - is it suddenly happening to all files and it was just one file before? Did you already try to reinstall Eclipse?

Answer (score 31):

I encountered this problem in my `filename.xhtml` using **Eclipse Mars**.

I got it fixed by:

**1.** Right click on the offending file.

**2.** Choosing Open With -> Default Editor.

After this, everything went back to the way it was.

Comment: Thank you. You solution has worked for me. Somehow I had "in-place editor" selected.

Answer (score 4):

Probably your File Association settings are messed up.

1. Open Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations.
2. Check if the file type (*.java) is in the list.

   1. If it's in the list, make sure the correct editor is selected as default.
   2. If it's not in the list, add it and assicate it with the correct editor.

Comment: Interesting, I have a similar problem but with .vm files and the file association was missing. I've added it but I still have the same error (but I'm part of the way there thanks)...

Comment: OK, it's also content type related for me (see this post too as the other part of the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063029/unsupported-content-type-when-open-html-in-eclipse)... So if I wanted to open .vm files in the HTML editor I'd need to go to Perferences > General > Content Types > Text > HTML and Add *.vm there too, hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

> 1. right click--> copy class
> 2. go to desktop and paste
> 3. back to eclipse right click delete the class
> 4. copy and paste from desktop

Thats works for me.

Answer (score 2):

**Had the same issue with .HTML files.**

Despite my File Associations were correctly set, the following is a **workaround** that solved the problem:

1. Right Click on the file of your project -> Open with
2. Check other Internal Editor -> select the Editor of your choice (my case = HTML Editor)
3. At the bottom, check "*Use this editor for all ... files*" + "*Use it for all..*"

Comment: Worked for me with .tex file (Probably I've clicked by mistake on in-place editor before). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and I fixed it by changing the workspace folder in Aptana: "General -> Startup and Shutdown -> Workspaces". I removed existing and added following one: "C:\Aptana_Studio\workplace" (instead of a workspace folder in my user profile).

JFYI: I found this error occurred after I've installed Eclipse for Java.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: This is not a question - the solution I described helped me in similar situation (the same error with OLE Exception).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I start my eclipse.
I fixed it by delete the **.project** file, and re-add the project to my workspace.