# Eclipse FXML Editor

Tags: eclipse, fxml

With Eclipse Ganymede I had syntax highlighting for java FXML files.
I updated to Kepler(4.3) and highlighting is gone; and so is formatting(Ctrl-i).
I tried the editors available on the open menu(System, Default).

Trying to open with the In Place editor gives a "OLE Exception" with this explanation: 
"This is probably because there is no OLE Editor registered against the type of file you were trying to open". 
So how can I solve the problem?

Comment: This may also be helpful for resolving this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464912/eclipse-cannot-create-in-place-editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `XML editor` listing in the right click `Open With` menu you can use that.
If the XML editor is not listed you can install it from the `Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development` section of the Kepler install (`Help > Install New Software...`).

You could also look at [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html) which provides more extensive support for JavaFX.